# Passing a WebElement parameter from a Cucumber feature into the Step Definition

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am attempting to pass a WebElement (instead of a String) from a Cucumber feature file into it's corresponding step definition.

```
Scenario: Test
    Given I want to click "myWebElement"
```

The corresponding step definition will be:

```
@Given("^I want to click (.*)$")
    public void Test(WebElement we) {
        we.click();
    }
```

At run time, I get the following trace:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Don't know how to convert ""myWebElement"" into org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.
Try writing your own converter:

@cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamConverter(WebElementConverter.class)
public class WebElement {}

    at cucumber.runtime.ParameterInfo.convert(ParameterInfo.java:150)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.transformedArgs(StepDefinitionMatch.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Is there a function that can be written for such a "converter"?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not passing a WebElement to the step definition but a string in the feature file. It depends whether that string parameter is an id or name or any other selector. Anyways you will have to extend the Transformer generic class as RemoteWebElement class has an empty constructor only.

Comment: In my case the WebElement is an identifier that exists in the page object class. In other words: @FindBy (css="input#ButtonClear") public WebElement ClearButton; I am passing "ClearButton" from the feature file

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to ask yourself why do you want to pass a `WebElement` as a parameter to a BDD framework.
BDD testing frameworks are usually used for acceptance testing, therefore the parameters should be something comprehensible even by the stakeholders.

Now, to come to your answer, Cucumber uses the so called Transformers to achieve this. Taken from the Cucumber documentation:

> public abstract class Transformer extends Object implements
>   cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverter
>   Allows transformation of a step definition argument to a custom type,
>   giving you full control over how that type is instantiated.
>
> Consider the following Gherkin step:
>
> Given today's date is "10/03/1985" As an example, let's assume we want
>   Cucumber to transform the substring "10/03/1985" into an instance of
>   org.joda.time.LocalDate class:
>
> ```
>  @Given("today's date is \"(.*)\"")
>  public void todays_date_is(LocalDate d) {
>  }   If the parameter's class has a constructor with a single String or Object argument, then Cucumber will instantiate it without
> ```
>
> any further ado. However, in this case that might not give you what
>   you want. Depending on your Locale, the date may be Oct 3 or March 10!
>
> This is when you can use a custom transformer. You'll also have to do
>   that if your parameter class doesn't have a constructor with a single
>   String or Object argument. For the JODA Time example:
>
> ```
>  @Given("today's date is \"(.*)\"")
>  public void todays_date_is(@Transform(JodaTimeConverter.class) LocalDate d) {
>  }   And then a JodaTimeConverter class:
>
>
>  public static class JodaTimeConverter extends Transformer<LocalDate> {
>      private static DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forStyle("S-");
>
>      @Override
>      public LocalDate transform(String value) {
>          return FORMATTER.withLocale(getLocale()).parseLocalDate(value);
>      }
>  }   An alternative to annotating parameters with Transform is to annotate your class with XStreamConverter:
>
>  @XStreamConverter(MyConverter.class)
>  public class MyClass {
>  }   This will also enable a DataTable to be transformed to a List<MyClass;>
> ```

I haven't tried it myself with `WebElement` types but the principle is the same.
You can find more information [here](https://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/Transformer.html).

Comment: Thanks. Even though I create a Transformer, the inherent problem of converting the String to a WebElement identifier still remains.

Comment: It seems that is built to work for any custom type, so you may want to check more in detail your converter. Basically a simple return driver.findElement(By.id(idVariable)); should do the trick.

Comment: How should the driver object be passed?

Comment: How does your transformer and test method code look like? What did you tried?

Comment: public class WebElementConverter extends Transformer<WebElement> {
 @Override
 public WebElement transform(String value) {
  return driver.findElement(By.id(value));
 }
}

Comment: And here's the step definition:

Comment: @Given("^I want to click (.*)$")
 public void Test(@Transform (WebElementConverter.class) WebElement we) {
  we.click();
    }

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is for java but heres what I did for same requirement in C# . I am adding just to help anyone who comes here looking for a solution in c# for same problem

You can achieve that with `[StepArgumentTransformation]` in  c# cucumber/specflow

```
  Scenario Outline: examples with step argument
  Given we have '<Webelements>'

  Examples:
  | Webelements | 
  |     Gmail   |
```

And step definitions are:

```
  using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
  using NUnit.Framework;

[Binding]
   public class Browser
  {
     private readonly BrowserDriver _browserDriver;
     public static  OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver driver ;

      public Browser(BrowserDriver browserDriver, FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        _browserDriver = browserDriver;  //your chrome driver
        driver = _browserDriver._driver;
        _featureContext = featureContext;
        _featureContext.Add("driver", driver);
    }

     [Given(@"we have '(.*)'")] 

    public void webelements(ChromeWebElement o)
    {
       Assert.False(o.Displayed);
    }

    [StepArgumentTransformation]
      public ChromeWebElement convertToWebElement(string c)
      {
        ChromeDriver parent = _featureContext.Get<ChromeDriver>("driver");
        return new ChromeWebElement(parent, c);
    }
```

obviously you get result `element is not attached to the page document` because I just used  `Gmail` element for test purpose

Answer (score -1):

Standard way to achieve this is to provide locator or reference of the locator as step argument and use create element from that in step. For example, with [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) you can have step like below:

```
    import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.ElementFactory.$;
    ...

    @Given("^I want to click (.*)$")
    public void click(String eleLoc) {
        $("eleLoc").click();
    }

    //blow is example using qaf step annotation
    //that doesn't need regex...
    @QAFTestStep(description="I want to click {element}")
    public void click(String eleLoc) {
        $("eleLoc").click();
    }
```

Above step can be called in feature file as below:

```
Scenario: Test
    Given I want to click "name=q"
```

if you are using [locator repository](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locator_repository.html), it may look like below:

**mypage_locators.properties**

```
page.myWebElement=name=q 
#add other locators for this page
```

Below is [self descriptive value](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locating_elements.html#self-descriptive-locator-syntax) for the same locator above

```
page.myWebElement={"locator":"name=q", "desc":"search text box on search page"}
```

Step can be called in feature file as below:

```
Scenario: Test
    Given I want to click "page.myWebElement"
```

You can use or refer inbuilt steps available for [web](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support), [mobile](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-mobile), [perfecto](https://github.com/Project-Quantum/Quantum) and [web-services](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws) and you can have your custom step implementation as well.